# Free a doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, memory, free

I have a doubly linked list in C and I'm confused as to how I should go about freeing it. I understand that I have to traverse the list freeing each node. Where the confusion lies is that each of my nodes has a pointer to some other data and I'm unsure how I should free that.

My doubly linked list looks like this:

```
typedef struct Node_ Node;
typedef struct List_ List;

struct Node_ {
    void *data;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};

struct List_ {
    Node *firstNode;
    Node *lastNode;
};
```

To free the list I've created a function called List_free() which traverses the list freeing each node with Node_free(). These functions look like this:

```
void *List_free(List *list)
{
    Node *next = list->firstNode;

    while(next)
    {
        Node *node = next;
        next = node->next;
        Node_free(node);
    }

    free(list);
}

void Node_free(Node *node)
{
    free(node->data);
    free(node);
}
```

Where this is going to fall down is where node->data is pointer to another struct that itself contains pointers. In my case I use the same list code to store two different structs.

The way I see it I have the following options:

1. Create lists where nodes hold specific data. Not very reusable.
2. Find another way to keep track of the pointers within the node data.

Am I thinking along the right lines or have I missed something obvious? This is my first attempt at C so I wouldn't be surprised if this is all completely wrong.

Comment: Hmm... I would use C++ and rely on destructors.

Comment: Good luck writing your OS or kernel driver or embedded app in C++ ;-)

Comment: @Alexander Rafferty: If you are going to change language to circumvent the issue, change to one with a garbage collector e.g. Java.

Comment: Why not change to Lisp - it has great support for lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to supply a function pointer responsible for freeing the node properly.

```
typedef void(*NodeDataFreeFn)(void*);
```

List_free is modified like this:

```
void *List_free(List *list, NodeDataFreeFn data_free)
{
    Node *next = list->firstNode;

    while(next)
    {
        Node *node = next;
        next = node->next;
        (*data_free)(node->data);
        free(node);
    }
    free(list);
}
```

Example data_free:

```
void data_free_fn(void* data_ptr) {
    // Add your custom stuff here.
    free(data_ptr);
}
```

Example call to List_free:

```
List_free(my_list, data_free_fn);
```

If you don't want to pass the data free function pointer by argument, you could store it into the List structure like this instead:

```
struct List_ {
   Node *firstNode;
   Node *lastNode;
   NodeDataFreeFn data_free;
};
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test this code, it may be buggy...

Comment: Why typedef the function pointer?  it -is- a function pointer.  It's not supposed to be masked or abstracted from the user.

Comment: Consider adding the data free function as a member of the node on  node creation.  That way, you can have lists with mixed data types or nodes with data not allocated from the heap.  e.g. a NULL data function would mean "don't free the data", so then you could put string constants in the list.

Comment: Thanks everyone. There were lots of similar answers all involving function pointers. I've accepted this one as it gave me the most to go on.

Comment: @Blank Xavier: it stops the parameter definition of the List_free function from stretching into the middle distance.

Comment: @Blank Xavier: because most people don't want to have to clutter their code up with all that every time they want to create one!  Are you still on your crusade against typedefs? (!)

Comment: @Oli: there are here two different factors which affect code readability. The first is the physical layout of the code; do we have a single word typedef type, or a full function pointer decleration? a single word is clearly physically more succinct. The second is an aspect of the logical layout; how much do we burden the user with requiring him to remember what the typedefs are? The use here of a typedef acts towards reducing the problems caused by the first factor, at the expensive of making the problems of the second worse. I view the second factor as far more significant.

Comment: Hmm.  I would correct the typo on "expensive", but apparently now SO limits the number of times you can edit a comment.  Like, WTF?  do the devs have nothing better to do than introducing ever more porportedly useful restrictions?

Answer (score 2):

You're not wrong, that's one of the problems 'solved' by OOP and in particular C++.

You could add a pointer to function member in your struct that would be used to free its data. Basically adding a C++ destructor by hand. That would keep genericity without too much duplication.

Answer (score 2):

If the application can store arbitrary data in your list, then is is also the responsibility of the application to arrange for proper cleanup.
This can be done in two ways:

1. Before calling `List_free`, the application must clear-out all elements of the list.
2. You add another parameter to `List_free` (and `Node_free`), which is a pointer to a deleter function:

   ```
   typedef void (deleter_t*)(void*);
   ```

   void Node_free(Node* node, deleter_t deleter)
   {
       if (deleter) (*deleter)(node->data);
       free(node);
   }

   For data that does not have to be freed explicitly, the application can pass a NULL deleter, for data that can be freed with a single `free` call, that function can be passed as deleter. For more complex data, the application has to pass a function that does the right thing.

Comment: Application may pass pointer to some sort of noop(), so check for NULL is not necessary.

Comment: @Vovanium: That is another possibility. I decided to use NULL to indicate no-op. Neither is inherently better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in the doubly linked list as the question indicates, but rather in composite dynamic structures. That's how manual memory management works: you have to keep track of what you have allocated. It's best to try to stick to node->data being the same structure every time so that a predefined routine can free it. Alternatively, use a marker on the structure and switch on the marker at runtime to choose between the deallocation routines for different structures (or just use a function pointer to simulate a C++ destructor).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm: create a `Data_free` function and call it for your data pointers.

```
void Data_free(void *ptr)
{
    /* first identify what data type ptr really is */
    /* and then deallocate memory used by ptr */
}

void Node_free(Node *node)
{
    /*free(node->data);*/
    Data_free(node->data);
    free(node);
}
```

---

*Edit:* change `struct Node_` definition, to make it more similar to a C++ class :-)

```
struct Node_ {
    void *data;
    void (*freedata)(void*);
    struct Node_ *next;
    struct Node_ *prev;
}
```

Comment: Where data is a void * I can use any type of data in the list. This is my issue. I use the same list code for different data types. If I created separate lists for each data type I intend to store I could do what you suggested.

Comment: You surely have some way to identify the data type of your void pointers, right? Just use that inside `Data_free`.

Comment: But then it's not reusable code anymore. Data_free would have to be changed every time a new data type is added.

Comment: The only other way I can think of involves changing the `struct Node_` definition and include a pointer to a function that frees the data memory ... see update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you may want to try is to implement a memory pool; which can be especially trivial to implement in case you don't plan to free nodes individually.

Simply `malloc` (or `mmap`, perhaps to `/dev/zero`) a large chunk and then you can "allocate" memory for one node by a simple pointer addition. De-allocating the entire list is then a matter of `free`ing (or `munmap`ing) the large chunk.

If done correctly, this may also give a slight performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you've identified something that is a pain to do in C manually, yet must be done. You can use function pointers to make the freeing mechanism generic to what your data is, but you still have to implement the mechanism to go down the hierarchy of data in each node to free everything up.

This is a good exercise and worth doing just for the learning experience.

But there's also a very useful library that will deal with all of this for you: [talloc](http://talloc.samba.org/). It keeps track of the hierarchy for you, so freeing the top level automatically frees up everything underneath. It is well documented. It was developed for samba and is still used there today, so is very well maintained.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't that the list has `prev` pointers. The issue is that every different kind of `Node` has a different way of deleting its contents.

So there needs to be a generic `Node_free` routine (which you have) and it needs to dispatch on the type of the node. So either the node needs to contain a generic type code, or it needs to contain a pointer to a destructor routine tailored for that node type.

Either way, you're basically doing what C++ does for you.